# implict conversion to StringOps not applied within a implict val function body

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion

In the following code snippet (using scala 2.10.3) **TestClass1** does not compile with error "*value toInt is not a member of String*" but **TestClass2** compiles fine:

```
trait TestTrait {
  implicit def test: (String => Int)
}

object TestClass1 extends TestTrait {
  implicit val test = (value: String) => value.toInt
}

object TestClass2 extends TestTrait {
  implicit def test = (value: String) => value.toInt
}
```

The *StringOps* implicit conversion via *augmentString()*, which provides the *toInt* function, is not applied in **TestClass1** but is applied fine in **TestClass2**. Can somebody tell me why this is the case and how to keep **test** a *val* instead of a *def*?

Comment: val is only evaluated once during lifetime of your TestClass1 object, therefore it can't have arbitrary arguments. If `value` was a member of your TestClass1 object, you could make it work : `object TestClass1 (value:String) { implicit val test => value.toInt }` but that's probably not what you had in mind?

Comment: That would only work with classes not objects, right? I'm definitely interested in using an object.

Comment: As far as I know, it holds for objects too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a limitation of implicit definitions when the return type needs to inferred, I think. You are in a somewhat similar situation as defining a recursive method. That is to say, the "open" implicit definition triggers implicit lookup in its body, which in theory could be recursive. (At least that's my explanation of this limitation).

You can either annotate the type:

```
object TestClass1 extends TestTrait {
  implicit val test: String => Int = value => value.toInt  // or _.toInt
}
```

or remove the `implicit` keyword—since it is implementing the implicit method from `TestTrait`, you do not need to re-state the `implicit` keyword:

```
object TestClass1 extends TestTrait {
  val test = (value: String) => value.toInt
}
```